# Excel function that states all "categories" that don't match

Tags: excel

I'm working on Google Sheets and I am having some difficulty coming up with a formula.

I am comparing two tables of information that look something like this, (but with way more columns):

[image: Table]

I have a function that tells me "TRUE" if the levels for each skill are greater than or equal to the required level, and "FALSE" if even one level is smaller than the required level for any skill.

Now, I need a function that, if even one skill level is less than the required level for that skill, it tells me all of the skill named that are too low.

Eg. In the case of the table above, the function should say "Skill 1, Skill 3". 
I was thinking about doing a very complicated "IFS" function, but I have about 20 skills and it would take a very long time to say "if first skill and second skill, first skill second skill third skill, ...." with every possible combination. Is there any way for a function to tell me the actual skill names that don't match up without writing it all out case by case with every combination?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably doable with TEXTJOIN.

Comment: You have this tagged as excel rather than google sheets, so I'm going to explain how I'd go about this in excel:

A table:
Three columns to start. Skillname, level, required level.

Then a calculated column of booleans-- whether or not the level is the target level.

Finally you could have a TEXTJOIN (or array formula concatenate) in conjunction with some fancy look-up to get a full string in a single cell.